# Do Scala function arguments become class variables?

Tags: scala, jvm

When calling a function in Scala, do the functions arguments become class variables for the FunctionN type that gets instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by function you mean an anonymous function, because that is when a FunctionN type will get instantiated.

The functionN's apply method will get called with the function arguments which per the docs will "Apply the body of this function to the argument."

Consider this:

```
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    def anonFun = (x:  Int) => x

    anonFun(5)
  }
}
```

If you look at the bytecode generated you'll see something like the following:

```
INVOKESPECIAL com/mf/Main$.anonFun$1 ()Lscala/Function1;
ICONST_5
INVOKEINTERFACE scala/Function1.apply$mcII$sp (I)I
```

INVOKESPECIAL loads the anonymous function, then the constant 5 is loaded and the apply method of the Function1 is called with the constant.

Comment: Is this 2.11 or 2.12? Somehow, I had expected it to look different in 2.12 with the new Java8-lambda-compatible encoding.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I ran it in 2.11, but in 2.12 the bytecode I presented is the same. What's different is in 2.11 a new anonymous class is created where anonFun$1 is defined, but in 2.12 Java8's INVOKEDYNAMIC is used to create a lambda expression.  So it is different, just not in the actual section where the anon function gets called.